# Телеграмм бот не реагирует на команды

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Всем привет, начал изучать питон и решил создать своего первого тг бота, но он по какой-то причине не реагирует на команду `start` (при этом эхо работает исправно). Буду рад, если поможете в решении проблемы

```py
import config
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def echo(message):  
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     'Привет, {0.first_name}! \nМеня зовут {1.first_name} и я бот, который поможет тебе выбрать '
                     'музыку под твое настроение.Внизу есть кнопки, которые ты можешь использовать для того, чтобы'
                     ' решить свои задачи.'.format(
                         message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html')
    sticker = open('hey.webp', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sticker)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: `/start` в первую очередь попадает в `content_types=["text"]` т.к. тоже является текстом. разместите обработчик `commands=['start']` выше обработчика `content_types=["text"]`

Comment: Буквально только что заметил это, когда удалил хэндлер с эхом. Благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы поставили команду "старт" под content_types=["text"], поэтому не работает

```
import config
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     'Привет, {0.first_name}! \nМеня зовут {1.first_name} и я бот, который поможет тебе выбрать '
                     'музыку под твое настроение.Внизу есть кнопки, которые ты можешь использовать для того, чтобы'
                     ' решить свои задачи.'.format(
                         message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html')
    sticker = open('hey.webp', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sticker)



@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def echo(message):  
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```